# asihttprequest always time out

Tags: timeout, asihttprequest

I am new to asihttprequest, I just use asihttprequest simply like:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setShouldAttemptPersistentConnection:NO];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

but in my `- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)` request, I often get a timeout error. When I connect to the same URL On Windows OS, it works fine. So I think it's not my sever problem, maybe the asihttprequest, can someone help me?

Comment: why i use "[request setShouldAttemptPersistentConnection:NO];",because some one have the same problem,he say it maybe a bug of the ASIHTTPRequest and he use "setShouldAttemptPersistentConnection:NO" and the request is ok,but i still have the problem.